# Should I generate my database query dynamically when the selected option changes?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'm generating a select option from a MySQL db. On a second query I'm displaying a list from the same db. I was going now to use JavaScript to match the first select with the second one, but I was wondering if it will be better instead of doing it like that to make a new query every time the selected option changes. Any ideas? Has anyone come across something like this, and if so, what was performing better?

```
include("conexion.php");

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `user_list` WHERE `user_id`=$oreo AND  `visibility` =  '0' ORDER BY `item_num` DESC ");
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT DISTINCT(`group`) FROM `user_list` WHERE `user_id`=$oreo AND  `visibility` =  '0'");

echo "<div> <select id='groopy' onChange='selectivo();'>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
    $group_name = $row['group'];
    echo "<option>".$group_name."</option>";
}

echo "</select></div>";
echo "<ul id='groopy'>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $group_name = $row['group'];
      $item_num = $row['item_num'];
      $tit_sup = $row['tit_sup'];
      $url = $row['url'];

      echo "<li alt='".$group_name."'>".$tit_sup."</li>";
}

echo " </ul>";
```

This is how I'm doing it now, I don't know exactly why but I don't really like it (it's not giving any problems but I'm guessing when there is a lot of content it would slow everything).

Comment: Hi @Daniel! I see you've been reversing the edits that users have made to your post. The users were really trying to help and to improve your question. It is generally accepted on [so], that anything not directly related to the question should be removed as it just adds "noise" to the post.

Comment: Things like "thanks in advance" or "might be a silly question" really don't contribute to the understanding of the question. In the future, if you are concerned about people possibly "defacing" your post, you should leave a comment asking what the rational is behind the edits. You'll find that people are very willing to explain exactly how you can improve your post so that you have a better chance for getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for a solution which will scale up to a big number of groups/users without too much impact on performance.

My ideas to that are:

- with a reasonable amount of data the current solution is the most responsible one, you already have everything at the user's side, and just have to filter the list on the selected group
- as the database grows, you could rewrite it a bit, and only load users for the selected group, and this could be achieved in two ways:

  - the whole page reloads on selection-change - this could be good for keeping the functionality working for browsers with disabled javascript, but I'd go for the next
  - first show an empty list - or a default one -, and load the userlist with AJAX when selection changes; this idea can be taken one step even further, in which you cache loaded userlists, and fill up the <ul> from the cache

For a better and more precise opinion it would be good to know when, how and for what you intend to use the group-selection and the userlist, but as of now, I see the above mentioned possibilities all to be available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the cache will be the best way I agree but it's cleared after every session, and reloading the whole page only for this piece doesn't seem right neither. I'll guess I'll steak to this until I can think on something running on the background or something else...but thanks again.